# "An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll"

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I was given a code to work on, as a beginner I didn't fully understand the code (a windows phone 8 Silverlight project using MVVM). the code has this

```
 public Dictionary<CeFlix.Entities.Enums.Views, string> PageRouting = new Dictionary<CeFlix.Entities.Enums.Views, string>()
    {
         {CeFlix.Entities.Enums.Views.DashboardPage,"DashboardPage.xaml"},
         {CeFlix.Entities.Enums.Views.LargeBannerDetailPage,"/Views/LargeBannerDetailPage.xaml"},
         {CeFlix.Entities.Enums.Views.ChannelDataPage,"/Views/ChannelDataPage.xaml"},
         {CeFlix.Entities.Enums.Views.ChannelDetailPage,"/Views/ChannelDetailPage.xaml"},
         {CeFlix.Entities.Enums.Views.VideoDetailPage,"/Views/VideoDetailPage.xaml"},
         {CeFlix.Entities.Enums.Views.UserLoginPage,"/Views/UserLoginPage.xaml"},
         {CeFlix.Entities.Enums.Views.UserRegisterPage,"/Views/UserRegisterPage.xaml"},
         {CeFlix.Entities.Enums.Views.UploadVideoDetailPage,"/Views/UploadVideoDetailPage.xaml"},
         {CeFlix.Entities.Enums.Views.FeedBackDetailPage,"/Views/FeedBackDetailPage.xaml"},
        {CeFlix.Entities.Enums.Views.EditProfileDetailPage,"/Views/EditProfileDetailPage.xaml"},
         {CeFlix.Entities.Enums.Views.ChangePasswordPage,"/Views/ChangePasswordPage.xaml"},
         {CeFlix.Entities.Enums.Views.MyPlaylistDetailPage,"/Views/MyPlaylistDetailPage.xaml"},
          {CeFlix.Entities.Enums.Views.SubscriptionDetailPage,"/Views/SubscriptionDetailPage.xaml"},
            {CeFlix.Entities.Enums.Views.SelectedSearchItemVideoPage,"/Views/SelectedSearchItemVideoPage.xaml"},
            {CeFlix.Entities.Enums.Views.CategoryDetailPage,"/Views/CategoryDetailPage.xaml"},
            {CeFlix.Entities.Enums.Views.WatchLiveVideoPage,"/Views/WatchLiveVideoPage.xaml"},
            {CeFlix.Entities.Enums.Views.CommentsPage,"/Views/CommentsPage.xaml"},
            {CeFlix.Entities.Enums.Views.CommentsPage,"/Views/RepliesPage.xaml"}
    };
```

I added two more pages to the project and I thought I could just add to the collection so I added two lines like this inside the PageRouting

```
,
            {CeFlix.Entities.Enums.Views.CommentsPage,"/Views/CommentsPage.xaml"},
            {CeFlix.Entities.Enums.Views.CommentsPage,"/Views/RepliesPage.xaml"}
```

The enum also looks like this, the last two lines represent the two new pages I added

```
 public enum Views
{
    DashboardPage = 1,
    LargeBannerDetailPage = 2,
    ChannelDetailPage = 3,
    VideoDetailPage = 4,
    ChannelDataPage = 5,
    UserLoginPage = 6,
    UserRegisterPage = 7,
    EditProfileDetailPage = 8,
    FeedBackDetailPage = 9,
    UploadVideoDetailPage =10,
    ChangePasswordPage =11,
    MyPlaylistDetailPage = 12,
    SubscriptionDetailPage =13,
    SelectedSearchItemVideoPage =14,
    CategoryDetailPage = 15,
    WatchLiveVideoPage=16,
    RepliesPage = 17,
    CommentsPage = 18
}
```

I had not seen this programming patter before. When I launch the App I an exception is thrown that say "An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll"
what do I do? can anyone help.
I think it's important I post this too

```
public void NavigateToPage(CeFlix.Entities.Enums.Views navigateToView, object navigationParameter)
    {
        string path = PageRouting[navigateToView];

        RootFrame.Navigate(new Uri(path + "?Param=" + navigationParameter, UriKind.Relative));
    }
```

When I now remove the two new lines of code I added to the PageRouting collection, it compiles fine, but I'm not able to navigate to those two new pages I just added.

Comment: You need to read what the exception says.  Almost every exception will contain all the information you need to fix the error.

Answer (score 2):

A dictionary requires unique keys, and you've added two entries with the same key - `CommentsPage`.

This looks like a typo, as you've added a `RepliesPage` enum value.  Should it be this?

```
{CeFlix.Entities.Enums.Views.CommentsPage,"/Views/CommentsPage.xaml"},
{CeFlix.Entities.Enums.Views.RepliesPage,"/Views/RepliesPage.xaml"}
```

Comment: sorry, could you explain in a simpler way, or elaborate, I don't seem to understand what you mean. because every page in the dictionary has an enum value

Comment: Yes, but you've used the same one twice. You can't have duplicate keys (and it doesn't make sense either).

Comment: but if you have a look at the enum content it's note true, each enum value has a different key (as you could see, serially 1 to 18). no two are the same

Comment: Look at the two routes you've added to the dictionary that break your code - you've added a route for `CommentsPage` *twice* with two different paths.

Comment: you are right, I just had to look at it line by line, the second one was supposed to be RepliesPage. Thanks man